# Communication between ros and android over usb

Tags: ros, usb, rosandroid, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm try to get the ros to communicate with an android app using a usb cable, so the computer and android app will talk to each other. I can only find examples of where wifi or bluetooth is used. I want to use the usb port. Wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to do this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201141/communication-between-ros-and-android-over-usb/) by [hat13](https://answers.ros.org/users/21397/hat13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on what version of android you're using, you can setup USB networking as "Internet pass-through" which will let you share your computer's network with the android device over USB. This will let you talk to a ROS nodes running on the android device like any other ROS node (or like you were using wifi).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hat13](https://answers.ros.org/users/21397/hat13/) on 2015-01-16**:
Using android 4.4.4. I'll give this a try and see if it works.

**Comment by [G212](https://answers.ros.org/users/25216/g212/) on 2016-01-27**:
Hi!! pleaseee can you tell me how you do that???